# How do I reinstall a base-R package (e.g., stats, graphics, utils, etc.)?

Tags: r, installation, package, built-in

I have been using the "stats" package in R 3.0.1 without any problems . But today i deleted the "stats" folder from the R library location and now I can't install it any more. I tried doing the same thing with other packages but I could install everything except "stats"

```
install.packages("stats", dep = TRUE, repos="http://cran.cs.wwu.edu")

## Installing package into ‘%Default R Lib Installation Path%’   
## (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)  
## Warning in install.packages :   package ‘stats’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

I also tried downloading it from other sources like "http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/" but nothing works . Any ideas?

Comment: I think you may have to reinstall the base R software, since `stats` is one of the included packages.

Comment: are you sure that it's a part of the default packages?

Comment: Yes, check the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Add_002don-packages-in-R)

Comment: yeah you are right , but i should be able to re install the "stats" package without re installing my R installation. I deleted another default package "rpart" and i was able to re-install it.

Comment: that's because `rpart` (in contrast to `stats`) is **not** part of the base R installation; thus it is not packaged for easy installation on CRAN.  I'm sure it's *possible* to restore the `stats` package without re-installing R, but I can almost guarantee that it will be easier to just re-install ...

Comment: If you *really* want to try something, you can start at https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/ and see what you can do ...

Comment: restoring is not a problem , i have a backup of the stats package but I just need to be able to install the "stats" package without re-installing R

Comment: Why?  As I said, I imagine it's theoretically possible, but it will be much easier to re-install R.  At a guess, it would take me about 15 minutes to re-install R, and I would feel lucky if I figured out how to re-install a base package on its own in less than an hour.  (The easiest way to do it would probably be to create another identical installation of R and copy the relevant directories to your existing installation.)

Comment: Perhaps you can copy/restore the relevant directory from your backup?

Comment: I apologize for not bringing this up earlier ; I have custom scripts that run on the user/client's machine and I install/load the required packages every time the script is run . So if somehow the "stats" package is deleted from the user's machine , I can't ask them to re-install R.

Comment: User-installed packages are stored separately from most of R, so re-installing R shouldn't touch your previously installed packages (although if you are attempting to do remote system administration on your client's machine, I would probably test the whole process somewhere else first).

Comment: e.g. see http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-UNinstall-R_003f

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Since SO is nagging me not to continue the comment thread, I will post an answer.)

I believe that this problem will apply to any base package (but not to those installed from repositories, and probably not to Recommended packages): I am deeply skeptical that `stats` is the *only* package. It should occur for any of the packages in this list:

```
rownames(subset(as.data.frame(installed.packages()),Priority=="base"))
```

I'm sure it's theoretically possible to re-install a base package from scratch, but it will be *much* easier to re-install R. At a guess, it would take me about 15 minutes to re-install R, and I would feel lucky if I figured out how to re-install a base package on its own in less than an hour.

I'm pretty sure that re-installing R will *not* affect previously-installed packages: see e.g. http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-UNinstall-R_003f; that link is about uninstalling rather than re-installing, but this seems relevant:

> Uninstalling R only removes files from the initial installation, not (for example) packages you have installed or updated.

Other choices would be

- create another identical installation of R (on another machine, or in a non-default location); locate the relevant directories in your new installation and copy them over to your existing installation.
- restore the relevant directories from your backup.

**PS**: obviously if you are doing this on a client's machine it would be a good idea to test my advice first ...

Comment: I verified and none of the base packages can be re installed. So i guess re installing R is the most easier and cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: If on OSX: I recommend installing R using Homebrew right from the start.  Then un/reinstalling it is as simple as `brew uninstall r`, `brew install r`.  This got my base packages back in less than a minute!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to copy the entire package folder from another to my `R.home()` directory.